# How do I change the interface language in Google Groups?

Tags: google-groups, localization

Today I logged into Google Groups and, to my horror, that the interface language changed to Hebrew, probably because I'm accessing the site from Israel. (I speak Hebrew, but rather not use it on the computer.)

How do I change the language? I couldn't find any link for changing it to English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place `?hl=en` before the `#` sign in the URL. For example:

> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!overview

Becomes:

> https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!overview

Comment: Awesome, `hl=en` worked.

Comment: This is great! I needed this for a google doc I sent to non-google collaborators. I added `?hl=en` to the end of the URL.

Answer (score 2):

It should respect your language preference set at http://www.google.com/preferences.  Does that make it permanent for you?

Comment: even if I set my preferences at the link you cited, the default language still reverts to my locale :(

Answer (score 0):

Go to Google home page in English and then on the right end of the screen next to sign-in option there is small block of tiny squares (Google Apps) click on that, a drop down menu appears, at the bottom click "more" and the menu scrolls up with another hyperlink **Even more from Google** at the bottom. Click on that link and Google products page opens up, now scroll down to the bottom. You will find "Groups" under the social tab. Click on this link and it opens up in English and then you may choose to sign-in.